# Expected type `Box<...>`, found type `()` when returning a boxed trait object from a factory

Tags: rust, traits

This question shows I'm a total newbie (coming from Java and looking into Rust for three days now). Searching online, I find lots of people asking the same question, and I do see answers stating that this is just not the way to use traits, but somehow I do not get how I can solve my problem.

I want to connect to two different stdin-stdout protocols. They are different to some extent, but they both start with their protocol name. So I'd like to dynamically choose which implementation of the two protocols I should use.

I tried the following:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

trait Protocol {
    fn parse(&self);
}

pub struct Abc {}
pub struct Xyz {}

impl Protocol for Abc {
    fn parse(&self) {
        println!("Hello to the BEGINNING of the alphabet");
    }
}

impl Protocol for Xyz {
    fn parse(&self) {
        println!("Hello to the END of the alphabet");
    }
}

fn get_protocol(line: &str) -> Box<Protocol + 'static> {
    if line.starts_with("Abc") {
        return Box::new(Abc {});
    }

    if line.starts_with("Xyz") {  // this gives error E0308, mismatched types
        return Box::new(Xyz {});
    }
}

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();

    // TODO: loop
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        let protocol = get_protocol(&line);
        protocol.parse();
    }
}
```

If that would work, I could call

echo "Abc" | ./demo_parser

But as stated in the comment, I get an error for mismatched types. I already added the `Box<..>`, and then the `'static` to it (found such examples on the web). I found another example using some `~` operator, but that was not specific enough for me to get it.

Can I either get this example working, or is it too much Java-thinking? But then, how can I solve my problem?

---

Thanks for your help. The question that is referenced as a duplicate did help me. However, it only helped my after several readings, due to the fact that that question had remarks on strings I thought it would not apply to my question. But it did, and since maybe this might help someone else, here is my modificated piece of code:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

trait Protocol {
    fn parse(&self);
}

pub struct Abc {}
pub struct Xyz {}
pub struct Unknown {}

impl Protocol for Abc {
    fn parse(&self) {
        println!("Hello to the BEGINNING of the alphabet");
    }
}

impl Protocol for Xyz {
    fn parse(&self) {
        println!("Hello to the END of the alphabet");
    }
}

impl Protocol for Unknown {
    fn parse(&self) {
        panic!("using protocol Unknown!");
    }
 }

fn get_protocol(line: &str) -> Box<Protocol + 'static> {

    if line.starts_with("Abc") {
        return Box::new(Abc {});
    }

    if line.starts_with("Xyz") {
        return Box::new(Xyz {});
    }

    return Box::new(Unknown {});
}

fn main() {

    let stdin = io::stdin();

    // TODO: loop
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        let protocol = get_protocol(&line);
        protocol.parse();
    }
}
```

This code works, but contrary to one of the comments it still needs the 'return', otherwise I get

not all control paths return a value [E0269]

Anyways, thanks to all of you for your patient help.

Comment: What happens if `line` starts with `ZZZ`?

Comment: *another example using some `~` operator* — sadly, even though Rust is young, there is still a lot of outdated information from before Rust 1.0. The `~` operator is one of them, and it's a sign that whatever reference you are looking at is very outdated. Also; you can just use `Box::new(Abc {})` instead of an explicit `return` - [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7fbbd97478eb9f507bf916ffc3f2188b&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: I apologize - I wasn't very clear in my previous comment, but I gave [an updated example that works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7fbbd97478eb9f507bf916ffc3f2188b&version=stable&backtrace=0). ^_^